# Arbitrator and choice of law

Tags: contract-law, international, consumer-protection, arbitration, alternative-dispute-resolution

Given the arbitrator is in California, and the dispute is related to say Consumer protection issues in UK, what will be the choice of law during arbitration process?

Answer (score 1):

### The location of the arbitration is irrelevant to the substantive law

For an arbitration in California, the *arbitration* process will be governed by Californian arbitration law unless the contract provides otherwise.

However, whatever law applies to the arbitration is irrelevant to the law that applies to the dispute. That will be decided by the arbitrator based on the submissions of the parties and their own expertise. Deciding what the law is is part of the arbitrator’s role.